# Can i use VideoCapture cap(0); from Kinect?

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

**Videocapture cap(0);** is function in *OpenCV*. But i have *Kinect*. So i want open the video used Kinect. How can I use kinect?

Comment: afair there is some inofficial driver package or sdk for depth sensors called openNI. OpenCV can be compiled with openNI support.

Answer (score 0):

Kinect camera has its own packages and libraries. You can not run it or open it directly using "VideoCapture" function. First of all you need to look into [here](https://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started) and install the packages. And you can also look into [here](http://mitchtech.net/ubuntu-openkinect/) if your operating system is Linux.